# Does tput automatically check color abilities when loading color codes?

Tags: bash, terminal, shell-script, colors, tty

When using `tput setaf` and `tput sgr0`, does it automatically output nothing if the session isn't tty-like or no color support is detected?

So am I fine doing this?

```bash
declare -r styleRed=$(tput setaf 1)
declare -r styleReset=$(tput sgr0)
```

Or do I need to do this?

```bash
if [ -t 1 ] && [ "$(tput colors)" -gt 7 ]; then
  declare -r styleRed=$(tput setaf 1)
  declare -r styleReset=$(tput sgr0)
else
  declare -r styleRed=
  declare -r styleReset=
fi
```

Comment: I don't think tput checks anything. It lets you happily destroy your session.

Comment: tput inspects your $TERM variable to see what the capabilities of the current terminal are and then assigns the correct codes (escape sequences) to the proper tput variables.  The only time I have seen a problem is when some odd sequence produces a terminal with no TERM set (uncommon).  The whole point of tput is to avoid needing to hand check and dink variables from term to term I believe.  You are probably better off checking to see if TERM exists.. if it doesn't `export TERM=dumb`.  I have never needed to do this.

Comment: `$ man terminfo ` is and `$ man curses` may be two places to start reading up on this, even if there is nothing more there for you personally than google-fodder.

Comment: How about some testing? `env -i tput setaf 1 | od -c`; `TERM= tput setaf 1 | od -c`; `TERM=dumb tput setaf 1 | od -c`; `TERM=xterm tput setaf 1 | od -c`; `term=xterm-256color tput setaf 1 | od -c`; `ssh -T localhost 'TERM=xterm tput setaf 1' | od -c`